# What is the max trainer level?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was wondering if anyone know how many levels your trainer can become in Pokermon Go?

Comment: Level 40, it seems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this](http://gearnuke.com/pokemon-go-max-trainer-level-cap/) article the maximum Level is 40. They found the information with datamining, there is no official statement about this.

Two more sources (thx to Kaz Wolfe): [source1](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L618) [source2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31116278#31116278)

You need 5 million experience points to reach from level 39 to 40.

Afaik at the moment (20.07) the highest level players reached is level 30 and they need 500k xp for level 31

Comment: @Anders: As one of the people who pulled the dump proving it to be 40, I can validate :) -- See [here](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L618) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31116278#31116278).

Comment: @Anders I can also confirm that this answer is the most correct information we currently have available.

Comment: <pedantic warning> The source1 link goes to an anchor tag describing the cpMultiplier levels.  To reference the XP points line, add about 47 lines to the anchor.